# EIG Protocol for Byzantine agreement

Tags: byzantine

There is an algorithm called EIG (Extra Information Gathering) protocol for Byzantine agreement of a bit over $n$ parties. The protocol has $t+1$ rounds. Can anyone help me understand how the time complexity of the algorithm is $\mathcal{O}(n^{t+1})$?

Comment: In [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221343953_Shifting_Gears_Changing_Algorithms_on_the_Fly_To_Expedite_Byzantine_Agreement) it talks about "**Exponential** Information Gathering with Recursive Majority Voting, or simply, the
Exponential Algorithm." Is this maybe what is meant instead of **Extra** Information Gathering?